# Arduino pro mini (clone) @1Mhz target does not answer

Tags: programming, arduino-pro-mini, usbasp

Recently I have been experimenting with battery powered sensor (mySensors).

I created node with 3.3V Arduino Pro Mini (ATMega328P @ 8Mhz with nordic radio chip and BME280 sensor) and successfully programed it many times using either USBAsp programmer or serial (to USB) programmer.

I wanted to lower power consumption and so I disconnected power led and burned fuses as follows:
lfuse 62
hfuse DA
efuse 7

It worked successfully and I recompiled the sketch and upload it with USBasp.
I got an error that data cant be verified. It was late in the night so I jumped to Internet and googled it. In one forum I found, post (which I am unable to find again) that stated the he was able to upload sketch when he switched programmer to 5V. (Power was connected to Vcc)

I did that and it worked fine.

Than I tried to make change to sketch and upload it again (on 3,3V) and again got verification error so I unplugged programmer and switched back to 5V.

When I did that, the device stopped answering.

I regularly used this command to check that device responds and see fuses

```
avrdude.exe -C"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -cusbasp -Pusb
```

What i did

1. Checked wiring.
2. Tried program fuses on blank new arduino - worked (programmer is
   fine)
3. Measured voltage ok
4. Measured current (its around 4mA, I see it as the board is not
   sleeping and is actively doing something)
5. I noticed that when I issue command mentioned above the on board led
   quickly lights up and then goes off again.
6. I tried to power it from raw, from Vcc and from Vcc on serial hader (picture).
7. I measured power on Vcc when connected to Raw pin and it reads 3.3V
   so power regulator should be ok.
8. I used -B10 switch to averdude with no luck

My question is

1. Is it possible that I burned the ATMega chip?
2. Is it possible that I see target not answering because of USBAsp is unable to lower programming frequency? (warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.)

Please suggest if there is anything I can try before throwing it out.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2017-01-07**
I was able to brick another board.
I think that the programmer is the cause.

I tried to upload bootloader with fuses from arduino and it failed with verification error.

I was able to burn bootloader from command line after seting fuses and restarting the board.

When I tried to upload the program it I got

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: lfuse changed! Was 62, and is now 0
Would you like this fuse to be changed back? [y/n] n
avrdude: safemode: hfuse changed! Was da, and is now 0
Would you like this fuse to be changed back? [y/n] n
avrdude: safemode: efuse changed! Was 7, and is now 0
Would you like this fuse to be changed back? [y/n] n
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:07, E:DA, L:62)
```

I answered yes because in in earlier attempts it just froze.

Now the board is in same condition as the first one.

Is it possible to revive it?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is link to post that suggests that I may burned the arduino.Method #6: Apply >3.3V to the 3.3V Connector Pin rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino. Strange thing is that it worked two maybe three times ok :-)

Comment: TL;DR if the AVR is running at 1Mhz you have to slow down the sleep of the USBasp. Use `avrdude  -B10 ....` to slow it down.

Comment: Ok, I need to solder jumper on USBAsp programmer. I will try in the evening and let you know.

Comment: That is another option. My solution is to just add `-B10`. Which seems easier than soldering to me.

Comment: I thought that USBAsp software must be upgraded to support this options, but it accepted -B10 and used 93750 Hz but result was still target doesn't answer.

Comment: You could try the jumper on the USBASP.

Comment: Ok I was able to brick another board using USBAsp programmer. I also solder the jumper with no effect. I updated the post, but dont know what to do. I dont want to brick any more boards :-). Should I look for another programmer?

Comment: What was the command you used to set the fuses? You can also lower the speed in software. I've had similar problems every now and then. Sometimes the -B10 didn't work. Sometimes only the jumper worked. Sometimes nothing worked, and then all of a sudden It did work. I'm still not sure what was going on.

Comment: @gaben I used avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cusbasp -Pusb -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0x07:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDA:m -Ulfuse:w:0x62:m. Do you think its fault of USBAsp? I was combining -P200, jjumper and it sometimes work sometime didnt and twice it bricked my board. Really dont know what is the problem.

Comment: Those are more sensible fuse setting then in the other post. Not sure what the `-P` flag does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this thread.

The board is probably not destroyed, more likely are fused corrupted.
There are ways of reviving ATMega328 chip and program fuses back its called [high voltage programming](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12898). You need to probably unsolder the chip or [modify your board](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=282705.15) (post from tontrack).

Also if you are wondering what to do or not to your Arduino board here is quite interesting page (you wil find it in comment).

I did not found a way how it could have happen but it did.

Anyway Iam done with UsbAsp programmer and ordered AVR pocket programmer. Until it arrives I stop any more attempts.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: How to destroy your Arduino https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/